# Linking to assets in Vuepress

Tags: vuepress

I want to keep related assets in the same folder as the relevant markdown.

```
+-- README.md
+-- some-folder
|   +-- index.md
|   +-- img
|       +-- example-screenshot.png
```

Displaying the image on the page is fine using:

```
![Some Alt Text](./img/example-screenshot.png)
```

*The location of the files when `vuepress build` is run is updated: /assets/img/my-new-img.ac30dec4.jpg*

However, if I just want a link to the screenshot the, the url isn't being processed correctly:

```
[See screenshot](./img/example-screenshot.png)
```

*The link comes out as '/some-folder/img/my-new-img.jpg'*

Not sure if this would be a bug, feature request, or if I'm not doing it correctly.

Answer (score 13):

You are using a relative URL, this has as a benefit that files are compiled into Vue components and processed by webpack. Your image is basically compiled, versioned (because of caching), copied to a new directory, plus the path has been updated.

You can read more here https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/assets.html#asset-handling

If you don't want that to happen, you can put your images in `.vuepress/public/`.

Afterward, you can reference it as `![img](/example-screenshot.png)` or if you use the `img/` subdirectory as `![img](/img/example-screenshot.png)`.

It becomes slightly more difficult if you have set a custom `base` in your `config.js`. However, you can rely in that case on html with something like `<img :src="$withBase('/foo.png')" alt="foo">`

Answer (score 1):

If you have the following file structure and want to keep the images in the respective folders and reference in custom components - you can also use an [alias](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/assets.html#relative-urls) in `.vuepress/config.js`. I think this is helpful when you want to keep things organized per group folder rather than in the `public` folder.

Folder Structure

```
docs/
--.vuepress/
----/layouts/
------/Tools.vue
----/Tools
------/wrench/
--------/wrench.png
--------/README.md
```

`config.js`

```
configureWebpack: {
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '@tools': '/docs/Tools/'
      }
    }
  }
```

README.md

```
<template>
  <Layout>
    <template slot="page-top"> // this ensures you have the global navbar
      <!-- My page content here -->
    </template>
  </Layout>
</template>

<script>
import Layout from "@theme/layouts/Tools.vue";

export default {
  components: { Layout }
};
</script>
```

Tools.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="Tools">
    <img src="~@tools/wrench/wrench.png" />
  </div>
</template>
```